# Construction of a certain compact set

Tags: measure-theory

I need some clarification in a problem I encountered in measure theory, which I am not sure I understand correctly. It states:

> Suppose $g:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $g>0$ and increasing
>   ($x<y \Rightarrow g(x)\leq g(y)$). Suppose also that
>   $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}g(x)=0$. Define $f_K(x)$ by 
>   $$f_{K}(x) = m\{t\in\mathbb R : |t-y|\leq x \text{ for some } y\in K\}$$where $K$
>   is a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ with $m(K)=0$ and $m$ is the
>   Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Find $K$ such that $f_K(x)\geq g(x)$
>   $\forall x>0$.

When I tried to solve this, I think that I came up with a counter-example. If we take $g(x)=3x$ then every requirement for $g$ is met. Now suppose that there exists a $K \subset [a,b]$ (as it is a compact set) with $m([a,b])=k$ such that $f_K(x)\geq g(x)$. For every $x$ we have that $f_K(x) \leq k+2x$ because if $t\not\in [a-x,b+x]$ then $|t-y| > x$ for every $y\in K$. But then we would have that $3x\leq 2x+k$ for every $x>0$ which is not true. Is there something I am not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on $g$.

Let $\bar{B} = [-1,1]$. Then $f_K(x) = m ( K+ x \bar{B})$.

If we let $b=\sup K, a=\inf K$, then we have $f_K(x) \le 2x+b-a$.

If $g$ is of the form $mx+c$ with $m>2$, then the inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Yeah, so you agree too that we can't find such a set without adding more restrictions to $g$. Thanks!

Comment: Yup! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$